# partition by query performance improvement

Tags: sql, partitioning, vertica

I have a query that gets first_value variables partitioned by app_id and mins and maxes of variables partitioned by tracking. the query takes too long to run (at least 6 hours). i am trying to reduce runtime.

the query is like the following (i have removed similar lines for brevity):

```
SELECT
FIRST_VALUE(app_ppl.rating_county_fips_code) OVER (PARTITION BY app_ppl.application_id
                                                        ORDER BY CASE WHEN app_ptn.requesting_coverage_ = 'true' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC) AS rating_county_code

    , MAX(CASE WHEN app_elig.csr_eligible = 'true' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY app_ptn.tracking_) AS csr_eligible

from

FROM
        (
            SELECT
            variables
            FROM daily_data.ins_appl
            WHERE coverage_year_number = 2023
        ) app_ppl;
```

I executed an explain plan and like I expected, most of the cost is coming from the first_value and max/min operations (i tested this by commenting out those lines and executing another explain plan).

I have tried segmenting on all nodes, bypassing the WOS and utilizing the ROS directly using /*+DIRECT*/.

I have read that indexing might help improve the partitioning first_value and min/max runtime. But i don't know how to do it. Is that the right direction to go in?

Comment: Can you add the existing physical design of `daily_data.ins_appl` ? Just run: `SELECT EXPORT_OBJECTS('','daily_data.ins_appl',FALSE)` and paste the output into your question, adding a line with three backticks before the output and a line with three backticks after the output

Comment: You should avoid CASE WHEN expressions in ORDER BY clauses of window functions. I will rewrite the query accordingly as soon as I know whether `'True'`and `'False'` are strings, in your case, or Booleans. The output I request here will tell me that.

Answer (score 0):

`'True'` and `'False'` work the same whether they are Booleans or Strings (FALSE is less than TRUE). So:

1. Change your code like so  :

```
SELECT 
  first_value(ins_appl.rating_county_fips_code) OVER (
   PARTITION BY ins_appl.application_id 
   ORDER BY ins_appl.requesting_coverage_  DESC
  ) AS rating_county_code
, max(ins_appl.csr_eligible) OVER (PARTITION BY ins_appl.tracking_) AS csr_eligible
FROM daily_data.ins_appl
WHERE coverage_year_number = 2023 
;
```

2. If not already done, make sure you have a projection on `daily_data.ins_appl` that is:
   `SEGMENTED BY HASH(tracking_,application_id)`